# What is the $L^2$ norm of a function which is any random of a point?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

For example, if I want to calculate the $W^{1,2}$ norm of $f=|x|$, then I calculate the weak derivative of $f$, which is
$$
f'(x)= 
\begin{cases}
1&x>0\\
-1&x<0\\
\alpha&x=0
\end{cases}
$$
I'm confused about the point $x=0$, how to deal with this point?

Comment: Weak derivatives are defined almost everywhere. This means you can change the definition of $f'$ on a set of measure zero and you will still get a weak derivative of $f$. In your case $\alpha$ can be anything.